# how to store blob data in sqlite database from javascript with google gear?

Tags: javascript, sqlite, google-gears

We have a very special requirement to store blob data in SQLite database, where We have to store documents. We have static html page which is in user disk, so we want user to upload document without connecting to internet with help of google gear, javascript and SQLite.

is it possible to do ...

Any Help Appreciated ...

Answer (score 1):

blob is possible yet [limited](http://code.google.com/apis/gears/api_blob.html)

see a detailed article in [here](http://www.ahmadsoft.org/articles/gearpush/index.html)

Comment: is there any way we can achieve to upload file in offline mode with google gear, javascript and SQLite.